# Filter in logstash a log4j2-Jsonlayout from docker gelf

Tags: docker, logstash, log4j2, gelf

Hello (I hope my english doesn't fail), I want to filter the json-message in logstash to use the json(all tags) in "message" as field in kibana.

**How I set my filter in logstash to include all json in the "message" in elasticsearch to show them in kibana as fields?**

I'm using log4j2 in my app to output the message to console with jsonlayout, then using docker gelf to output to logstash, then to elasticsearch to show in kibana (thats the requiriement), is in this way beacuse I need the threadcontext and the docker-container information.

This is my complete log in kibana

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2019.04.30-000001",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "YRagb2oBpwGypU5SDzwG",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@version": "1",
    "command": "/WildFlyUser.sh",
    "@timestamp": "2019-04-30T19:02:01.550Z",
    "type": "gelf",
    "message": "\u001b[0m\u001b[0m19:02:01,549 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) {\"thread\":\"default task-1\",\"level\":\"DEBUG\",\"loggerName\":\"com.corporation.app.configuration.LoggerInterceptor\",\"message\":\"thread=INI\",\"endOfBatch\":false,\"loggerFqcn\":\"org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger\",\"instant\":{\"epochSecond\":1556650921,\"nanoOfSecond\":548899000},\"contextMap\":{\"path\":\"/appAPI/v2/operation/a661e1c6-01df-4fb6-bf35-0b07fc429f5d\",\"threadId\":\"54419181-ce43-4d06-b9f1-564e5092183d\",\"userIp\":\"127.17.0.1\"},\"threadId\":204,\"threadPriority\":5}\r",
    "created": "2019-04-30T18:54:09.6802872Z",
    "tag": "14cb73fd827b",
    "version": "1.1",
    "source_host": "172.17.0.1",
    "container_id": "14cb73fd827b5d0dc0c9a991131f55b43a302539364bfc2b7fa0cd4431855ebf",
    "image_id": "sha256:6af0623e35cedc362aadd875d2232d113be73fda3b1cb6dcd09b12d41cdadc70",
    "host": "linuxkit-00155d0cba2d",
    "image_name": "corporation/appapi:2.1",
    "container_name": "appapi",
    "level": 6
  },
  "fields": {
    "created": [
      "2019-04-30T18:54:09.680Z"
    ],
    "@timestamp": [
      "2019-04-30T19:02:01.550Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1556650921550
  ]
}
```

this is the json in the "message", I want to include all the fields:

```
{
    "thread": "default task-1",
    "level": "DEBUG",
    "loggerName": "com.corporation.app.configuration.LoggerInterceptor",
    "message": "thread=INI",
    "endOfBatch": false,
    "loggerFqcn": "org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger",
    "instant": {
        "epochSecond": 1556650921,
        "nanoOfSecond": 548899000
    },
    "contextMap": {
        "path": "/appAPI/v2/operation/a661e1c6-01df-4fb6-bf35-0b07fc429f5d",
        "threadId": "54419181-ce43-4d06-b9f1-564e5092183d",
        "userIp": "127.17.0.1"
    },
    "threadId": 204,
    "threadPriority": 5
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Yea, srry. How I set my filter in logstash to include all json data in elasticsearch to show them in kibana as fields?